# Resolve Mysql query to Select unique from id and order by date acceding

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im new to msql! Can any one re-correct me

My table name = `details`, column = `id`, `name`, `mobile`, `email`, `city`, `state`, `Pincode`, `difftime`

1. I need to retrieve data unique by ID,
2. get count on Id retrieve on desc order
3. difftime(Datetime) in Asc order

Please help me on this,

```
select * from details 
where id s 
join (SELECT id FROM `details` 
      group by id 
      ORDER BY `difftime` ASC,count(id) desc) d
on d.id=s.id 
ORDER BY s.`difftime`  
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: If I'd is unique, why are you trying to use group by on it, or order by count of id which will always be 1? This makes no logical sense.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause has to be after all the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses. You also have no conditions in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Please post output you want.

Comment: i got the format Now I needed only unique id (no duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  D2.*, D1.* from details D1
left outer join (SELECT D.id, count(*) as total_ids FROM `details` D 
      group by D.id 
     ) D2
on D1.id=D2.id 
ORDER BY D1.`difftime` ASC, D2.total_ids  desc
LIMIT 5
```